# Comparing list A and B with a function that choose the larger number and gives it a name

Tags: vba

Im not very good at coding and trying to learn.

Right now I have two lists "Strategy A" and "Strategy B" that includes a long list of random numbers. I am trying to create a code where the function chooses a scenario and then compares the values within the strategies and labels it with "A" is that value is bigger and vice versa.

Currently I have this:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 9 To 1008
    For j = 9 To 1008
        If Sheet.Range("C" & i).Value > Sheet.Range("D" & j).Value Then
        result = "A"
    ElseIf Sheet.Range("D" & j).Value > Sheet.Range("C" & i).Value Then
        result = "B"
    ElseIf Sheet.Range("D" & j).Value = Sheet.Range("C" & i).Value Then
        result = "AB"
    End If
Next
```

I get invalid outside procedure when I use this code, and I get move on to the next part.. Which is creating a Sub with a FOR loop that reads the values and leaves the result in a result column.

I would to get some help on this!

Thanks!

Comment: BTW what is result you haven't defined it is it a range ? Variable ?

Comment: Functions need to be stored in Standard Modules, like: Module1 and not be stored in a Sheet module, like: Sheet1, to work universally.

To call a function you need to be within a "Sub" or use them in a Cell as you would any standard Excel function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Sub largestnum()
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 Dim wk as worksheet
 Set wk = sheet1 'change it to your sheet number

For i = 9 To 1008
For j = 9 To 1008
    If wk.Range("C" & i).Value > wk.Range("D" & j).Value Then
    result = "A"
ElseIf wk.Range("D" & j).Value > wk.Range("C" & i).Value Then
    result = "B"
ElseIf wk.Range("D" & j).Value = wk.Range("C" & i).Value Then
    result = "AB"
End If
Next j
Next i
End sub
```